# How to clean tomcat cache?

Tags: java, caching, tomcat, jar, virtual-machine

I use code like:

```
  Thread currentThread=Thread.currentThread();
  ClassLoader classLoader=currentThread.getContextClassLoader();
  InputStream configFile=classLoader.getResourceAsStream("config.xml");
```

But this code starts to work after 2 - 3 hours. I didn't nothing - only restart, clean, deploy, etc.

I suppose that old jar/class that cannot find file config.xml was in some cache - may be in cache of tomcat or in cache of OS/VM. Does it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand your question. What do you mean by 'code starts to work...'?

Comment: It means that found config.xml

Comment: The problem that config.xml is in jar file in WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately i can't make comments i dont have 50 reputation yet so i will just write my comment into this answer,

Can you explain more about the code? What tool do you use to prepare the code? How do you deploy it ? My assumption is that if you "only" make a restart, clean and after a deploy it will not work, do it the other way, clean, deploy, restart. If you give more information, i can give you a better answer.

What you can try to do is delete the application cache or set the caching off if you believe its a caching issue

cachingAllowed="false" in confg/context.xml

Comment: this is half comment half answer :D